# how to draw a count plot for the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my pandas dataframe and I want to draw a countplot for train, test, val with hue as 0 and 1 in the same count plot, how can I do this?

```
   train  val  test
0     78    9    11
1    124   15    16
```

thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Please see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'train': [78, 124], 'val': [9, 15], 'test': [11, 16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.plot.bar()
```

[image]